# Power BI Oracle connetion - Details: "Oracle: "

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I'm trying to access Oracle DB from Power BI, but always get following error message: "We encountered an error while trying to connect. Details: "Oracle." ". Connection to DB is working for me when tested with SQL Plus or other tools. At the same time, colleague of mine can access same DB from Power BI, with same Oracle client. Don't you have an idea what could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking on how to connect POWER BI Desktop to an Oracle Database in order to build reports or universes. Power BI PaaS Service in Azure only supports data from Oracle using a Gateway, and you can't refresh the reports.

- Install the version of the Oracle Client in your PC ( 32 bits or 64 bits ).
- Open Power BI --> Home --> Get Data --> Oracle Database

Here is the interesting thing

[image]

In the SERVER you must put the TNS connection STRING in the format:

```
MYSID=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydnshostname)(PORT = myport))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = MYSID)))
```

Next window, select database credentials and put your user and password.

**UPDATE**

To me , the error "Oracle:" looks like a missing component:

- Instant Client 32bits
- ODAC Oracle Data Access Components 32bits

or the version of Power BI was downloaded from Microsfot Store. Use this link instead

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494

Comment: Thanks for reply, but not really. I know how to connect to Oracle DB from PowerBI, but when I do it, I always get an error mentioned in the first post.

Comment: exactly, nothing else, just that

Comment: did you install ODAC in your laptop or just the instant client ?? which version of ODAC are you using 32bits or 64 ? It looks like there is a missing component

Comment: where did you get the Power BI Desktop version ? from Microsoft Store ?

Comment: Thanks for your support Roberto, I have PBI from store and ODAC121021_x64 and client 12c

Comment: that is perhaps the problem. You can't use the version from STORE with Oracle. You need the one you can download from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494